# Как добавить внешний идентификатор для объекта "IsKey" (имеющего два значения)?

Tags: sql, delphi, key

При любом добавлении нового объекта, на типе которого установлен признак "IsKey", нужно присваивать новый ВнешнийИдентификатор объекту. Поле ВнешнийИдентификатор на форме ввода объекта в таком случае должен быть не доступен для редактирования.

IsKey имеет два значения:
1 - стоит галочка
0 - не стоит галочка

Comment: *При любом добавлении нового объекта, на типе которого установлен признак "IsKey", нужно присваивать новый ВнешнийИдентификатор объекту.* А ежели IsKey не установлен, то новый идентификатор не присваивать... оставить какой был, старый... у нового объекта... угу. Вы бы получше продумали формулировку вопроса, что ли.

Answer (score 1):

> При любом добавлении нового объекта

Добавлении куда? Какого объекта?

> на типе которого установлен признак "IsKey"

Есть какой то свой тип, или признак установлен с помошью аттрибута, или речь идет просто о записи в таблице?

После n-го прочтения могу только догадатся что:

- есть какой то набор данных (грид например с колонками, одна из колонок `IsKey` - `Id` записи) При добавлении новой строки нужно сгенерировать `Id` для всех где `Id = 1`. Выполняем в цикле:

  `if (<Новый объект> and Field['IsKey'] = 1) then  ВнешнийИдентификатор = <новое значение>`
- на форме также есть поле, которое отображает инофрмациб об `IsKey` - нужно запретить его редактировать.

  `поле.ReadOnly := true`